# Compare uid and get username

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL table `fe_users`I have the columns `uid` and `username`.

In my MySQL table `quiz` I have the column `uid` which has the same values as the column `uid`from the table `fe_users`.

How can I run a query that returns all usernames from the table `fe_users` which match with `uid`?

Comment: I suggest a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) is what you need

```
SELECT fe_users.* from fe_users INNER JOIN quiz ON fe_users.uid = quiz.uid
```

> An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables,
>   based on a common field between them.
>
> The most common type of join is: SQL INNER JOIN (simple join). An SQL
>   INNER JOIN returns all rows from multiple tables where the join
>   condition is met.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT fe_users  from fe_users INNER JOIN quiz ON fe_users.uid = quiz.uid